# Android Submenu not working

Tags: java, android

I"m new to the world of Android, so i'm learning android with a tutorial found on the net !
i made the same code as written ,but when i click on the submenu it doesn't show anything !
even the android default icon not showed !!
please i need help.
this is the code:

```
package com.example.menus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        SubMenu m = menu.addSubMenu(0,2000,0,"Sous menu");
        m.add(0,1000,0,"Menu1");
        m.add(0,1001,0,"Menu2");
        m.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i("",""+item.getTitle());
        Log.i("",""+item.getItemId());
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case 1000: Toast.makeText(this, "menu1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();break;
        case 1001: Toast.makeText(this, "menu2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: I get 'Sous menu' and then 'Menu1/Menu2' as expected. What's the API level/version of your device/AVD? What's the min and target SDK in your manifest?

Comment: I'm using Android 4.4 API level 19. in the Manifest i got this :  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: i changed targetSdkVersion to 19 and the submenu is not displayed

Comment: Okay, I've tried your code on 4.4, min=8, target=18 and it continues to work for me. I get the overflow menu in the action bar (3 dots) which opens 'Sous menu' which in turn opens the choices 'Menu1 / Menu2'. If I choose one, I get the Toast displayed. Do you not get the same or are you expecting to see something else?

Comment: When i click on "Sous Menu" i got nothing ! no submenu displayed ! :(

Comment: I have tried android 4.3 all is working fine !!so the problem comes from Android 4.4 thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` write code like below

```
menu.add(0, Menu.FIRST, 0, "Name of menu")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon) 
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu); 
return true;


onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch(item.getItemId()) 
{
    case R.id.action_home: 
    Toast.makeText(this, "menu1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
}
}

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_" />
</group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Please explain what it does.